# Can I attatch my garden hose to a hose bib on the water main?

Tags: plumbing

I was looking for a hose fitting closer to the front of my house when I noticed this valve with what appears to be threaded for a hose fitting right off my water main next to the water meter (*Blue circled in the picture below*).

Can I just screw my garden hose into it like normal and use it without blowing something up because of pressure or something?

I am not sure if attaching a garden hose so close to the water main will mean it's over-pressurized or something.  I don't know about plumbing at all.

As a side note; why are there three water main valves (*yellow valves*) all so close together (*2 right away at the wall and one more after the water meter*)?

If I ever need to turn off my water main does it matter which of the 3 valves I use?

The water main comes into the house from the street in the wall in the upper right.

[image]

Comment: You'd need to [edit] to include a picture for anyone to have a hope of answering your questions about the valves. As for pressure, it depends what your supply pressure is, and whether it's so high that you need a pressure reducing valve. On the third hand, there are garden-hose-thread inline PRVs just for hoses available for not much money, so you could do that if needed. One reason for valves before and after the meter is to allow changing the meter with minimum fuss.

Comment: oops, forgot the picture, I've updated with the pic

Comment: The area in blue is very small. All i see is a  valve with a handle, not a hose bib.

Comment: yeah it has a very simple thread that seems to be hose sized - just like this one https://i.pinimg.com/originals/ea/67/5c/ea675c921aaa64465f083d7ec78c33d1.jpg

Comment: Is this valve on the upstream side of the meter? In the pic it looks like it is...

Comment: valve is downstream - the water comes in from the upper right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: For temporary uses, hooking a hose up to this one should be fine.

There is typically a drop in pressure and volume from the water main to the hose sillcock because of the distance, 90-degree elbows, and smaller diameter pipe in between.
Sillcocks close to the water main with full-diameter pipe have better flow so they're more useful for irrigation and such - sprinkler systems are installed as close to the main as possible and with pipes as large as possible for this reason.

This valve probably exists there for drainage purposes, so a short hose can be connected and run to a floor drain/sump pit/toilet. This relates to all the yellow-handled quarter-turn valves that cut off the flow, then the hose can drain water away from that section.

If you're using this for non-drain purposes you'll want to make sure your hose has decent strength, a good rubber gasket, and is screwed in tightly to make sure it doesn't leak. A slow drip on a hose connection outside is fine. A slow drip on a hose in this location would be much more problematic.

Ideally, install a regular (weatherproof/vacuum breaking) sillcock in a convenient location outside as soon as possible and use that instead.

Answer (score 2):

Of course trying to determine why something was done years ago is speculative. My guess would be that the valve on the left was the original shutoff. The hose connection may have been a whole house drain. This would allow you to drain the plumbing in the event of a no heat situation or long term absence. The two yellow ball valve were likely added during a meter upgrade or when it was determined that the original shutoff did not completely stop the flow of water. My primary concern with using it would not be pressure but  the age of the valve.It looks older than the valve on the left based on handle design. It is possible that it may leak when you try to shut it off.